# Implicit conversion shared_ptr to bool

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr, implicit-conversion

I was wondering why the bool conversion operator of a shared_ptr works fine in an `if-statement`, but not in the implicit conversion to the (bool) return value..

```
std::shared_ptr<const OfflineContainer> m_pContainer;   

bool MyClass::IsInitialized() const
{
    if (m_pContainer) // compi;es
        return true;

    return m_pContainer; // won't compile
}
```

The compiler message: 
`Error C2440   'return': cannot convert from 'const std::shared_ptr<const MyClass>' to 'bool'`

Comment: It's because [the conversion operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_bool) is marked as `explicit`. That means you can't make implicit conversions (as is done in the `return` statement).

Comment: See also [When can I use `explicit operator bool` without a cast?](/q/39995573/4850040)